# python mysql.connector fetchall() run extremely slow

Tags: python, database, mysql-connector

I have a simple sql query using python and mysql.connector

```
query = 'SELECT age, score FROM patient'
cursor.execute(query)
dr = cursor.fetchall() or cursor.fetchone()
print(dr)
```

In phpmyadmin, this query is very fast (0.003s).
It also runs fast in Python if I use fecthone(). However, it becomes extremely slow if I use fetchall(). Sometimes it take a few minutes and prints result. Sometimes it simply failed and halt.

My data is about 440,000 lines. I want to actually plot score against age, so I have to read all data out. Someone can help me?

ps: if I get rid of fetchall(), fetchone() and print, it runs very fast. But then how do get my data and plot it?

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but have you tried `MySQLdb` or something like [`ultramysql`](https://github.com/esnme/ultramysql)?

Comment: Thanks. I haven't. Maybe I should try it.

Comment: there is no way it should take a few minutes to query half a million rows ... how slow is the computer you are using?  plotting half a million rows I can see being somewhat slow but not fetching ...

Comment: I haven't tried plotting yet. Just fetching it now. It works fine in phpmyadmin. I am using an i5 4G for your information

Answer (score 2):

Fetching *all* 440k records can legitimately be slow.

If you want to draw a plot, you usually don't need 440k points; your screen is likely only about 2000 to 4000 pixels wide, 100-200 times smaller. You can show parts of the plot fetching only relevant part of the data, or you can pre-compute a scaled-down version (IIRC MySQL does not have native table sampling support).

As a side note: if you care about database performance at all, routinely [inspect query plans](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html). A plan for fetching one record can be drastically different than a plan for fetching all of them, and they likely will have different priorities if your database serves many concurrent requests. This all affects data latency significantly.

Comment: thanks for the solution. I actually want to get all the data and do some analysis first. that's why I need all data. Plot it on screen is the first thing I can think of.